# How to find the scrollable width of a UL with overflow:auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-lists, overflow

I have a UL with the following style:

```css
#sortable { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    overflow:auto; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The UL will span the size of my browser window and apply a scrollbar at the bottom, which is great. Now I would like to get the width of the scrollable section. I thought something like `$("#sortable").scrollWidth` or `document.getElementById('sortable').scrollWidth` would work, but it returns undefined.

Is it possible to determine the width of the UL at any given time? I also need to support IE8. Thanks.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vzp68/4/

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: `document.getElementById('scrollDiv').scrollWidth` should work

Comment: Remember, `$(".scrollDiv").scrollWidth)` gets elements with the *class* `scrollDiv`. I think you're looking for `$("#scrollDiv").scrollWidth)`.

Comment: just get rid of that bracket at the end, will ya'...? ;)

Comment: ...adding to @DanielLisik's comment, you're probably also not targeting the right id, as in your css you have `#sortable` while you're looking for `scrollDiv` in js, unless you're using a var (not sure as you haven't shared the rest of your js code)...

Comment: Sorry for not referencing the correct item in my sample code above. This is what I'm calling to try and show the width: alert(jQuery("#sortable").scrollWidth)

Comment: `$('#sortable').scrollWidth` won't work; `scrollWidth` is a property of an element, not a jQuery property. What do you get when you do `document.querySelector('#sortable').scrollWidth` or add a `[0]` before `.scrollWidth`?

Comment: @Jacob I originally tried document.getElementById('sortable').scrollWidth but someone suggested jQuery. I've added a jsFiddle link and will try your suggestion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scrollWidth` isn't a jQuery property, so `$('#sortable').scrollWidth` won't work. `$('#sortable')[0].scrollWidth` will, however, as [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vzp68/5/) demonstrates. `document.getElementById('sortable')` and `document.querySelector('#sortable').scrollWidth` also appear to work in the fiddle.

Comment: THanks! I'm not sure why the getElementById() didn't work for me before (it's in my description), but I must have had some other syntax issue. Here is the working link: http://jsfiddle.net/Vzp68/7/. Thanks for your help!